# Design criteria for an output LC-filter

Tags: analog, design, filter, class-d

When designing an output filter for a simple class-D amplifier I am unsure about sizing the components. Given:

- cut off frequency of approximately 50kHz
- the inductor DC resistance can be disregarded for this question
- the load is 8Ω, for this discussion purely resistive
- this architecture:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffdSqW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The center frequency for the LC filter is:
$$f_c = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$

Possible solutions include (but not limited to):

\begin{array}{|c||c|}\hline L & C \\
\hline
220\text{μH} & 47\text{nF}\\
22\text{μH} & 470\text{nF}\\
2.2\text{μH} & 4.7\text{μF}\\
220\text{nH} & 47\text{μF}\\
\hline
\end{array}

What are the proper design criteria for choosing a larger or smaller inductor / smaller or larger capacitor?

Comment: what is your PWM frequency?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't want to discuss the choice of PWM-frequency vs. cutoff frequency, that design decision is probably worth a question in its own right. The PWM frequency is much higher than the 50kHz.

Comment: Ah if only it were as simple as that - at where the filter cut-off may be pitched you might want to examine what the speaker impedance looks like (especially if switching is sub 200kHz) - this might cause another resonance peak that is closer to your PWM frequency. At well-above audio frequencies I can envisage the speaker acting just like an inductor - that's my reason for asking dude because you can't rely on the 8 ohms for damping anymore. Also, what power output are you considering or are you OK working out whether inductor saturation will be a problem?

Answer (score 7):

You must consider the load, which the loudspeaker creates for your LC filter.
It changes the response of the filter.
Below are results of the simulation performed with [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice) for different
values of L and C (keeping almost constant the LC product):

[image: Results of simulation for different L and C values (with constant LC product)]

As you can see, from the tested values
330nF, 33µH gives the best results (I have added this set of values basing on results of simulation).

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} L & C & \text{color} \\
\hline
220\text{μH} & 47\text{nF} & \text{violet}\\
33\text{μH} & 330\text{nF} & \text{turqoise}\\
22\text{μH} & 470\text{nF} & \text{red}\\
2.2\text{μH} & 4.7\text{μF} & \text{blue}\\
220\text{nH} & 47\text{μF} & \text{green}\\
\end{array}

From the point of view of the loudspeaker (R1) we have a parallel RLC circuit. Its Q factor is defined by the formula: $$Q = R_1\sqrt{\dfrac{C_1}{L_1}}$$

For C1=330nF, L1=33µH the Q factor is equal to 0.8

The optimal solution will be the one, for each Q is equal to 1.

Comment: Very helpful answer, basically the load dampens the resonance from the LC combination and that needs to be aligned.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If one wants to provide any theoretical background, it should be necessary to analyze the Q factor of the RLC circuit created by the L1, C1 and R1 (speaker). 
For the highest value of L1, the circuit behaves almost as a low-pass RL filter consisting of L1 and R1 (the influence of C1 is visible only above 300kHz).

Comment: If you might drive different speakers, remember they aren't all 8 ohm loads and most hi-fi speakers use L-C filters as crossovers. So it may be worth re-run the simulation with a variety of different speaker models (4 ohm, 8 ohm, and a typical crossover network) before making a final decision.